# Error with Poky bs on vserver

Tags: linux, compiler-errors

i try to build an Image with yoctos poky on my vserver (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS minimal - Vserver 64bit)

With my own pc with the same ubuntu version i don't have any problems to build the image, but on my vserver i get a lot of errors like this one:

```
ERROR: Execution of event handler 'run_buildstats' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_buildstats(e)", line 85, in run_buildstats(e=<bb.build.TaskSucceeded object at 0x7f5f79df6c10>)
  File "buildstats.bbclass", line 2, in get_device(e=<bb.build.TaskSucceeded object at 0x7f5f79df6c10>)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/yocto/yocto/poky/build-hd/tmp/buildstats//.device'
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not your system error.but it was generate by bitbake and somewhere python scripting execution failed by bitbake.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yes,you are right.but I faced sometime this issue.there was bitbake unable to compile source code and it was stuck in execution event handler. you can find more details here : https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html